# Row and Column of square Sudoku (f.e. square 34)

Tags: algorithm, sudoku

Every square has a number from `1 to 81`. The first cell (with 5) is numbered 1 and the last cell (with 9) is numbered 81.

The square with the red cross in it is numbered **34**. If I am given this number knowing it's a 9x9 sudoku how can I calculate the Row and Column of that square?

In this example the row is **4** and the column **7**.

[image: sudoku red cross]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple! If c = cell number which is given as input

Row_number = ⌈c/9⌉

Column_number = c-((Row_number-1)*9)

Answer (score 0):

```
index = (row - 1) * 9 + column
row = (index integer_division 9) + 1
column = index - (index integer_division 9) * 9
```

Comment: Row calculation fails when `index = 1`.

Comment: `(1 modulo 9) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1`
What would you expect?

Comment: Ah, sorry, Im confusing my operation names again. My modulo should ofc be integer division.

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.